# UITableView inside UIView with 20px Top Space constraint

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I have a "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." in my iOS app log that I cannot understand or fix.

I have a bunch of UIViews going vertically down my UIViewController. Each of them have a set height, in this case 120px, with a Top Space constraint to the view above it and a Bottom Space constraint to the view below it.

[image]

Then inside the view there is a UITableView with a 20px Top Space constraint. That means when the height of the view changes the table view will get bigger but still have its 20px top space.

[image]

This works perfectly and gives no warning at the Storyboard level, but gives the following error to the console:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.     Probably at least one
>   of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try
>   this:         (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect;         (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint
>   or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "< NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f939bf47b30 V:[UIView:0x7f939bf5ad20(0)]>",
>       "< NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f939bf47bd0 V:|-(20)-[TabItemsTableView:0x7f939a944400]   (Names:
>   '|':UIView:0x7f939bf5ad20 )>",
>       "< NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f939bf47c20 V:[TabItemsTableView:0x7f939a944400]-(0)-|   (Names:
>   '|':UIView:0x7f939bf5ad20 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   < NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f939bf47c20
>   V:[TabItemsTableView:0x7f939a944400]-(0)-|   (Names:
>   '|':UIView:0x7f939bf5ad20 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

The 20px Top Space is to give the effect of a separator that only separates the views if their table views have rows, otherwise their height is set to 0 and the whole view disappears. If the 20px Top Space was on the parent view then when the height is 0 the 20px would persist.

Comment: Does this tableview also have height constraint ?

Comment: How many is a bunch?  Do you actually have enough height on the display to fit everything in?  Remember the storyboard view isn't the same as the device view

Comment: @BharathVankireddy It does not.

Comment: @Russell the views are dynamic. I have the height of 120px set, but that is linked to the view controller and its height is updated depending on how much content is inside it. This warning is most likely happening when I make the view 0px in height..

Comment: I think so.  what happens if you hide it instead of shrinking it?

Comment: Conflict between 2 constraints . One is top space and other constraint  have a value of '0' which you have to figure it out. And then remove one of these 2 constraints, that will solve conflicts issue.  Or select resolve constraints option from storyboard , some cases this will help.

Comment: @Russell hiding the view means that it still has that height, it will just be a large empty space as it is still constrained to the height of the view.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have solved this problem. It was happening because I had the top margin of 20px and then I was setting the parent view to a height of 0, so it didn't know whether to listen to the top margin of 20 or bottom margin of 0 constraints for a view with height of 0.

To fix this issue I set the priority of my top 20px constraint to 999 (when the default priority is 1000) so that this constraint is ignored when a choice needs to be made between the two.